# Detect whether a time was specified in a DateTime object

Tags: php, datetime

I have a list of dates, some with times:

```
01/03/2014
02/01/2014 02:00 PM
02/02/2014 1:00 PM
03/01/2014
```

I am going through all of these and turning them into `new DateTime` objects, sending them to JavaScript, then using moment.js to display them.

```js
moment(data.date).format('L LT')
```

This displays the dates in the following format:

```
01/03/2014 12:00 AM
02/01/2014 02:00 PM
02/02/2014 01:00 PM
03/01/2014 12:00 AM
```

Is there a way to detect, without regex (or whatever string manipulation), that the `DateTime` constructor was called with *just* a date (without a time)?

Comment: Isn't that Javascript, not PHP?

Comment: @Barmar: I assume he's using JS to display the dates:  "*sending them to JavaScript, then using moment.js to display them.*".

Comment: @Barmar: Sorry if I confused you, but the dates start out in PHP.  I turn them into objects (`new DateTime($date)`), then I `json_encode` it for an AJAX request.  moment.js is only for formatting.

Comment: @RocketHazmat you want to determine whether the input string contained only a date, by inspecting **only** the DateTime object?

Comment: AFAIK, the `DateTime` object contains no information about the original string.

Comment: @salathe: That's what I want to do, yes.  I can do it with Regex, but I wanted a better solution.

Comment: Would using [`date_parse()`](http://php.net/date_parse) on the input string be okay? It returns false for missing parts of the date/time string.

Comment: @salathe: Actually, I think that could work!  I'm not *actually* using `DateTime` but my own class that `extends` it, so I could add `date_parse` to the constructor! :-D

Comment: Great. If not, or you're wanting to be sure of certain discrete formats*, then a sequence of `DateTime::createFromFormat()` and inspecting `DateTime::getLastErrors()` might be useful… I guess that depends on precisely what you're wanting. (*In so much as the method will allow this.)

Comment: @salathe: I guess I could try one format and if that fails, try the other.  I was using this code for other formats, too, but that's another solution.

Comment: Very nicely phrased question, @Rocket. +1

Comment: I've posted an answer before reading the comments here that contained the very same idea @salathe had. Just wouldn't be fair if I kept the answer. However http://pastie.org/8863133 that was what I came up with. Just for referential reasons.

Comment: @salathe: I just found that there's a [`date_parse_from_format`](http://php.net/date_parse_from_format) function! :-D

Comment: @RocketHazmat absolutely, there are many ways to skin this cat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think DateTime class provides a way to detect if the object was actually created from *just* a date. That information is lost once the object is created. A small-work around is to use [`date_parse()`](http://php.net/date_parse) to check for absent date time fields (as *@salathe* mentioned in the comments).

If the DateTime doesn't contain a hour, minute or second part, then it means it only has a date part in it. Using the above logic, your code would look like:

```
$datetimes = [
    '01/03/2014',
    '02/01/2014 02:00 PM',
    '02/02/2014 1:00 PM',
    '03/01/2014'
];

$withTime = array();
$withoutTime = array();

foreach ($datetimes as $dt) {

    $parts = date_parse($dt);

    if ($parts['hour']   === FALSE &&
        $parts['minute'] === FALSE &&
        $parts['second'] === FALSE) {
        $withoutTime[] = $dt;
    } else {
        $withTime[] = $dt;
    }

}

print_r($withTime);
print_r($withoutTime);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 02/01/2014 02:00 PM
    [1] => 02/02/2014 1:00 PM
)

Array
(
    [0] => 01/03/2014
    [1] => 03/01/2014
)
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/111928)

Comment: Hmm, why the downvote? Is there something wrong with this answer? I'd like to improve it if possible.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted either.  I like this solution, the `date_parse()` function should be able to solve my issue.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: You can keep the question open for a few days if you'd like. That way more people will see the question and you might get a better answer!

Comment: Yeah, that's a good idea.  I won't forget to mark an answer ;)